# What is the right mixed effects models for data that is both nested and not?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, clustered-standard-errors

I have a dataset that includes nested observations as well as repeat observations that are not nested (I'm not sure this is the best way to describe it, but stay with me).

Here are the specific details on the data:

I have data on amendments considered on the floor of the House of Representatives. Each amendment is nested (or grouped) by bill, since an amendment can only be offered to one bill. I understand that if this were it for complications with the data I would just run a multi-level model.

HOWEVER, the data are also clustered by the sponsor of each amendment. Amendments are sponsored (or offered) by individual members of Congress. Some members of Congress appear just once having offered just one amendment in the dataset. Other members of Congress appear dozens of times having offered dozens of amendments. The sponsor are not hierarchically nested within each bill as members can and do offer amendments to numerous bills.

My question is what is the most appropriate model, allowing me to deal with the multi-level nature of the data (amendment - bill) and the repeated observations by sponsor?

I'd know how to deal with each of these independently, but not at the same time. I'm lost. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of a couple of lines of your dataset ***sorted*** to show what you mean by "nested observations" and "repeat observations that are not nested?"  Sometimes a picture is worth more than a verbal description of the data that you have.  Seems like an interesting research topic, by the way

Comment: What statistical package are you working with?

Comment: ![screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/Ubm1kWJ.jpg).

Comment: You can see that there are amendments (amend_id) nested within bills (bill). In other words, each amendment is group under one bill (like students nested/grouped into classrooms --each student is in only one class). Each amendment has a sponsoring member (sponsor_id), but sponsors can repeat. A sponsor could offer an amendment to several bills, and/or several amendments to one bill. I bolded one example of a sponsor showing up multiple times across bills.

Comment: I use STATA a stats package.

Comment: A random-effect model would allow you to model both nested and crossed random effects.  According to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36148/three-level-mixed-effects-crossed-and-nested-model-in-stata), it is possible to fit such a model in stata.  I don't know if your response looks particularly Gaussian.  What is your inferential question?

Comment: what's your outcome?  And yes, Stata can handle multilevel models for different kinds of outcomes (depending on version), or you can use the non-native user-written `-gllamm-` command if all else fails

Comment: My dependent variable is dichotomous (whether each amendment was accepted or rejected on the floor). What I am trying to determine is if cues given by particular members of Congress influence the likelihood an amendment is accepted. The key independent variables are trichotomous indicators measured for each amendment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *cross-classified* dataset structure, in that it features (partially) crossed random effects of "bill" and "sponsor." The appropriate model is thus a (generalized) linear mixed model with crossed random effects.

Cross-classified data structures are common in fields like experimental psychology and linguistics -- for example, a common experimental setup involves a sample of participants who all make some response to the same sample of printed word stimuli -- but perhaps not as common in other social science fields, so they have not been as widely studied as hierarchical data structures. But they are commonly applied in certain areas.

Most modern mixed modeling software (but not all) can support models with either crossed or nested random effects. In Stata it looks like the appropriate command would be the `xtmelogit` command, considering your binary outcome. Unfortunately I can't help you much with the exact syntax.

I have compiled a [reading list](http://jakewestfall.org/misc/LMM_reading.html) on introductory mixed models, geared toward cognitive science researchers, which features many papers that focus on crossed rather than nested random effects. I guess you're not a cognitive scientist, but you may still find it useful.

Comment: Thanks! My only remaining question then would be for anyone who knows 'xtmelogit'. How do you distinguish between crossed and nested random effects with this command? Or is it not necessary to specifically distinguish?

Comment: @JimCurry In all the stats packages I've seen that will fit crossed random effects, you don't need to use any special syntax to fit them, you just specify the random factors separately and everything works fine. So the syntax will pretty much look the same as if it were a 3-level hierarchical model (and in fact these two models are basically identical in a deep sense -- the fact that the two random factors happen to be crossed rather than nested in the dataset doesn't actually have any important consequences as far as the model fitting is concerned).